# problem in my python code that eye blinks are too many detected. (using Eye-Aspect-Ratio method)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect human eye blinking in video using openCV and python.

So, I found a very effective example code in github, and I am refactoring it.

My code was implemented based on EAR(Eye-Aspect-Ratio) method, Invented by Tereza Soukupova and Jan Cech in 2016.

eye_aspect_ratio() takes six points around the eyes and calculates the absolute area of the horizontal axis and vertical axis.

This is figure of eye aspect ratio method :

[image]

this is my code:

```
def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)
    return ear

# (...)
# face detection using face_cascade
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cropped = frame[y - int(h / 8):y + h + int(h / 8), x - int(w / 8):x + w + int(w / 8)]
    rects = detector(cropped, 0)
    for rect in rects:
        shape = predictor(cropped, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
```

However, there is a problem in my code that eye blinks are too many detected.

I think, my code misdetects that it is not eye blinks (e.g. smiling eyes or winking)

Is there something point I missed?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, eye blinks occur simultaneously in both eyes.

Thus, you should use the value which sums and divides in half the eye’s ratio through using the cost of the `leftEAR` and `rightEAR`

I think using this method will solve some of the problems.

You can try this code:

```
leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

# use this value
EAR = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
```

Finally, use a value less than `0.3` when comparing the `EAR` to the `threshold`

Thank you. good luck.